# Automation of entity reading in yesod

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to automate entity reading in my yesod application.

This is what I have:

```
withEntity
  :: ( PersistEntity a
     , YesodPersistBackend site ~ PersistEntityBackend a
     , PersistStore (YesodPersistBackend site)
     , YesodPersist site )
  => String
  -> Key a
  -> (Entity a -> ExceptT Text (HandlerT site IO) b)
  -> ExceptT Text (HandlerT site IO) b
withEntity what key f =
  do mrec <- lift . runDB . get $ key
     case mrec of
       Nothing  -> throwError . pack $ "unknown " ++ what
       Just rec -> f (Entity key rec)
```

Users of my application may send a request for data in DB using integer ID instead of `Key a`. So I have a wrapper around `withEntity`:

```
withEntitySql
  :: ( PersistEntityBackend a ~ SqlBackend
     , ToBackendKey SqlBackend a )
  => String
  -> Int64
  -> (Entity a -> ExceptT Text (HandlerT App IO) b)
  -> ExceptT Text (HandlerT App IO) b
withEntitySql what key f = withEntity what (toSqlKey key) f
```

This way I can write functions specifying error messages when record doesn't exist:

```
withA
  :: Int64
  -> (Entity A -> ExceptT Text (HandlerT App IO) a)
  -> ExceptT Text (HandlerT App IO) a
withA =
  withEntitySql "A"

withB
  :: Int64
  -> (Entity B -> ExceptT Text (HandlerT App IO) a)
  -> ExceptT Text (HandlerT App IO) a
withB =
  withEntitySql "B"
```

I can combine this functions with each other:

```
withA aId $ \ ea ->
  withB bId $ \ eb -> do
    ...
```

On the top level in handler for route I wrap the result of `runExceptT` into json object so client can see if something went wrong with his request.

I don't like that I have to write a function for each entity I'm working with in order to specify error message. I'm not sure how to improve `withEntity` to determine error message by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would experiment with something like the following:

```
import Data.Typeable

withEntitySql
  :: ( PersistEntityBackend a ~ SqlBackend
     , ToBackendKey SqlBackend a
     , Typeable a )
  => Int64
  -> (Entity a -> ExceptT Text (HandlerT App IO) b)
  -> ExceptT Text (HandlerT App IO) b
withEntitySql key f = withEntity (show $ typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy a)) (toSqlKey key) f
```

Comment: For working version `forall a b .` constraint is required plus `ScopedTypeVariables` extension. That's what I need, thanks!